# what kind of transition strip do I need to use to transition from 1/8" vinyl tile in dining room to low pile carpet in adjoining living room?

Tags: flooring

what kind of transition strip do I need to join 1/8" vinyl tile in dining area to low pile carpet in adjoining living room area?

Comment: Is everything down already? Or are you pre-planning?

Answer (score 1):

You may not even need a transition if they are both laid down well. Otherwise, you could use whatever you want. I'm thinking a thin metal or wood one would look decent.